# Wrong result when counting nodes in list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is my query:

```
WITH ["a", "b", "c", "d"] as list
MATCH (n:Node)-[]-(g:Group)-[]-(n2:Node) WHERE n.name IN list
RETURN g, COUNT(n) AS intersection, COUNT(n)+COUNT(n2) AS groupSize
```

where basically, I want to count all the elements present in group g, as well as the intersection  size between the list and the group.

Problem: the result is wrong

```
intersection = {number of Nodes connected to Group g} - 1
groupSize = 2 * ({number of Nodes connected to Group g} - 1)
```

What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

You should not use a `MATCH` pattern containing a pair of `Node` nodes, as that creates a lot of duplicate occurrences of each node. Also, the same pair will be found twice (in reverse order).

This query will probably do what you want:

```
WITH ["a", "b", "c", "d"] as list
MATCH (n:Node)--(g:Group)
WITH list, g, COLLECT(n) AS ns
WITH g, SIZE(ns) AS groupSize, SIZE([x IN ns WHERE x.name IN list]) AS intersection
WHERE intersection > 0
RETURN g, groupSize, intersection
```

Comment: Thanks. Except that your query also returns groups where the intersection is empty.

Comment: That was intentional. But since you want the intersection to be non-empty, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I learned how to filter multiple times consecutively and this gives the wanted result:

```
WITH ["a", "b", "c", "d"] as list
MATCH  (n:Node)--(g:Group)
WHERE n.name IN list
WITH g, COUNT(n) as intersectionSize
MATCH (n2:Node)--(g)
RETURN g, COUNT(n2) as groupSize, intersectionSize
ORDER BY intersectionSize DESC
```

I was hoping for something more concise, but well...